# angular is not detecting change in input field

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

we are making an extension that scans the input field and fills some data into it.
I am using the .value operator to fill the data.
The problem is, it works in almost every case except the angular material input. I am able to set the value of the input, it displays in the field but somehow angular is unable to detect change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to dispatch an input event

```
target.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input', {bubbles: true}));
```